# automated line breaks in LaTeX tables

Tags: latex

In my dissertation, I have a glossary that explains some abbreviations I use. I put this in a table to make it look nicer. However, LaTeX does not break lines at the end of the page.

I know that I could force a line break at any point in the table, but it is a long table (much work!) and manual line breaks make the text look jagged and ugly. Is there a nice way to either have a nice-looking glossary or make LaTeX break lines automatically in a table?

...if LaTeX wouldn't do these things every so often I would really love it. The way it is, I constantly switch between affection and anger...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

look at the `longtable` package. it handles pages breaks automatically. 
http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but my question is about line breaks, not page breaks

Comment: in which case you can say:
`begin{longtable}{l >{\raggedright}p{0.75\textwidth} }`
and your lines will break automatically at the table edge & at the page break ;)

Comment: you bet. you can define the width of table cells using p{width}, then the >{\raggedright} before that makes all the text in that column sit ragged right.

Comment: because I can't withdraw my downvote, but longtable handles line breaks *and* page breaks whereas tabularx (see below) only handles line breaks. So, yours is the best answer! And if you edit your response to include the details you wrote in the comments, I will even upvote it!

Comment: Lol. Oh well. Good luck with your thesis! I hope it's typeset beautifully... Make sure you switch to a font other than CMR :P

Comment: Also see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35348/errors-with-ragged-right-justification-in-tables if you get noalign errors.

Comment: For anyone who is using @Mica's solution from the comment for `longtable`s: As pointed out by @Leo, noalign errors will definitely occur when you use double backslash. My simple work-around: `\begin{longtable}{|l|p{0.95\textwidth}|}` (don't use `\raggedright`)

Answer (score 62):

Why are you using a table for your glossary? Are you aware of the [glossaries](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package? It lets you create beautiful glossaries with a minimum effort.

If you still want to use a table, I suggest you to use the [tabularx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), it defines the `X` column type which creates columns of adjustable width with word wrapping.

For example:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

...

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |l|X| }
  \hline
  word1 & long definition... \\
  \hline 
  word2  & long definition...  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Found this page via Google... This solution worked great for me!

Comment: I needed a simple table, no glossary. This answer is perfect and the example works straightaway!

Comment: For everyone using `booktabs` and don't want vertical lines, use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ lX }` instead.

Answer (score 9):

try:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
Long text here & Long text here & Long text here \\
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked in my case:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
one line& \parbox[t]{5cm}{another\\column}\\
second line here& and here
\end{tabular}
```

(Found on the [answer to a similar question on TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-to-break-a-line-in-a-table/486#486).)

Answer (score 0):

Insert after each `\\` (or `\cr`) the following:

```
\noalign{\penalty -100 }
```

Example:

```
\def\penlt{\noalign{\penalty-100 }}

\halign{&\hfil\ (#)\ \hfil\cr
1&2&3\cr \penlt
1&2&3\cr \penlt
1&2&3\cr \penlt
1&2&3\cr \penlt
1&2&3\cr \penlt
1&2&3\cr \penlt
1&2&3\cr \penlt
1&2&3\cr \penlt
1&2&3\cr \penlt
1&2&3\cr \penlt
1&2&3\cr \penlt
}
```

If you want to use the rule after each line then write

```
\def\penlt{\noalign{\hrule \penalty-100 \hrule height -.4pt \hrule}}
```